# Установка службы Windows

Tags: c#, windows-service, служба

При попытке установить службу получаю следующую ошибку:

> Отсутствуют общие программы установки с атрибутом
>   RunInstallerAttribute.Yes в сборке
>   C:\Users\аыва\source\repos\EDIService1CConvert\EDIService1CConvert\bin\Debug\EDIService1CConvert.exe.
>   Удалите файл InstallState, поскольку отсутствуют программы установки.

Ошибка мне понятна и я знаю что делать нужно - добавить `Installer`, но раньше у меня все инсталилось через  CMD без него, что сейчас не так, почему нужно использовать его? Раньше я имя службы и путь указывал в команде через CMD. `Удалите файл InstallState` - где найти его? Объясните пожалуйста что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Ранее я использовал команду:

```
sc create asperacentral binPath= "C:\Users\выавыа\source\repos\EDIService1CConvert\EDIService1CConvert\bin\Debug\EDIService1CConvert.exe" DisplayName= "EDIService1CConvert"
```

А ошибку получил использовав :

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
```